# Meaning of $dx$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If I remember correctly, we use $ Δx$ for changes in $x$ and when $Δx \rightarrow 0$ then  $ Δx$ takes the form of $dx$?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: that is the question...is this the said meaning?

Comment: I don't see any question here. Please reword the question.

Comment: I just told you it...

Comment: The answer is given here: http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/11/03/more-than-infinitesimal-what-is-dx/

Comment: The notation $dx$ is meant to evoke the idea of $\Delta x$, but it is merely notation for a concept that is *related* to what happens as $\Delta x\to 0$. In particular, $dx$ is not a number, while $\Delta x$ is a number.